# Collapse and Expand Table of Contents in Kindle PaperWhite

Tags: kindle-paperwhite

How to collapse and expand the Table of Contents from the "Go To" menu? Last night I accidentally discovered that the TOC can be expanded for quick jumping using the goto icon. I had hard time to find the way to collapse the expanded chapters/sections how ever I accidentally manage to collapse it by clicking random places (but I guess I clicked repeatedly on "Contents" tab) but not sure how exactly it is done.

**Update**

I forgot to mention that all the sub sections in TOC was auto expanded (I am sure I did not expanded individual section by clicking the triangle). I know that I can collapse it by clicking on the triangle again on individual section but there must be something to collapse and expand all at once.

Answer (score 1):

There is a right-facing black triangle (▶) on each menu item that can be expanded, clicking on which the menu expands and the triangle becomes downward facing (▼) which again is clickable to collapse the sub-menu.

I see how easy it is to miss given the arrows are very small in size.

Comment: I am sorry for missing out to mentioning this point. Please check my updated question

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question correctly. I did find that if I expand multiple chapters I can collapse them together by clicking the Contents button.

Comment: yes, that collapse all must be by clicking on the "contents" which I mentioned in my original post. there must be some way to expand all also which I did accidentally

Comment: No idea really.